# Should .limit() be called before or after .where() . orderBy()?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

for example , i have the following

```
  void getMessages(){

        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').collection('chat')
            .limit(10)
            .where('isDeleted',isEqualTo: false)
            .orderBy('messageTime',descending: true)
            .get()
            .then((value){

        });
      }
```

now i see many article videos, some call `.limit()` at the first and some call it at the end
i am confused . is that difference could make sense ?

what is the best way to call `.limit()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter to the API where you call `limit`, as long as you don't call it more than once.

I tend to put limit as the last call on my query as I find that easiest to read, but that's a preference and not a requirement from the API/SDK.

Comment: thanks now i understand . As far as I know, the program calls occur in order according to the first . Don't you think the queries are easier to read after limiting the data? What I imagine is if i call queries at the first so queries will be on everything in the server before knowing the limit . Of course I don't doubt you i just want to understand how does it easiest to read if the queries was at the first without to know the limit yet . thanks

Comment: If you've coded a lot of SQL, I think you automatically put the doesn't-matter-ordering things in SQL order. :)